# Hidding iframe when element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, load, hide

I have an Iframe that is hidden and when the function load finish it changes the visibility.

I do this because on the load function I do some changes to the iframe styles, like some elements I hide and a background color change so the user don't see the old styles, and when it finish then I change the iframe to visible.

Now I have a problem, when the user does click on a element that goes to another page, the old styles display until the iframe load function finish and changes the styles again.

I would like to change the visibility of the iframe to hidden when the user click on this element and then on the load function it will change the iframe to visible again.

Right now I'm doing this:

```
$(function(){
    var f=$('#foo')
    f.load(function(){ 
        var css = '<style type="text/css">#_____c, #navTabs {display: none;} body{background: white;}</style>';
        f.contents().find("head").append(css);

        document.getElementById("foo").style.visibility = 'visible';

        f.contents().find("#_bw0__r").on('click', function(event) { 
            document.getElementById("foo").style.visibility = 'hidden';
        })
    });
});
```

But when the user interacts with some elements of the iframe the onClick function doesn't work on the next page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    f.contents().find("#_bw0__r").on('click', function(event) { 
        document.getElementById("foo").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    })
```

Put it outside f.load(function)

Comment: document.getElementById("#_bw0__r").on('click', function(event) { 
        document.getElementById("foo").style.visibility = 'hidden';
    })